# Maximum amount of time a workflow can run

Tags: workflow, pause

Is there a a limit to how long a workflow can run using the Pause function?

I seem to have found that workflow history is deleted after 90 days, but would this have an effect on the workflow if it is still running at that time?

In theory, could a workflow run forever if performing an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think their is any such limitation on the workflow timing.

Workflow history deleted after 60 days(be default),after a workflow is completed or cancelled. In other words, Workflow Auto Cleanup only delete the history items for the completed /cancelled workflows.

> Workflow history items themselves are not deleted, but the entry point
>   to view them on the status page for a particular instance will no
>   longer be available.

Workflow Auto Cleanup job is responsible for this which runs daily.If you dont want to clean the workflow history list, you can disable this timer job.

[Disable automatic cleanup of workflow history](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hi Waqas, do you know if this applies to Sharepoint Online by any chance?